# How to implement a RX room query

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

I'm quite new to `Room` and `RXJava` and I want to use them to perform a quite simple query but I have problem implementing the RX part and handle results.

```
@Dao
interface DepartmentDao{
//....
@Query ("SELECT employeesIds FROM Department WHERE Department_name LIKE :name")
 fun getEmployeesIds(name:String):String //this is a jsonArray stored as string
}
```

Then I have `Kotlin` object where I write some other methods related to the database others than ones from `@Dao`

```
object DBManager {
  fun getEmployeesIdsJsonArray():Completable = Completable.fromCallable {
        mDataBase.DepartmentDao().getEmployeesIds(deptName)
    }
}
```

I want to query this in my Fragment and use the query result (a string in this case) when the query completes. This is where I get locked and need your help.

```
DBManager.getEmployeesIdsJsonArray()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( //here I get locked, how can I handle this?)
```

I expect to have something like

```
{
  onSuccess -> jsonString , //this is the string resulted, feel free to use it
  onError -> Log.e(TAG, "query failed")
}
```

but I'm not able to implement it successfully without all kind of errors regarding type expectations.

Comment: "all kind of errors" what errors?

Comment: I don't mean errors in console, I mean errors when trying to write code like: `Type parameter bound is not satisfied`, `Required: Action! Found: Action1<Throwable> ` etc. I'm not able to write the subscribe() part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Completable returns nothing, just termination event onComplete/onError

Try :

- Return Single in your Dao
- Your subscribe method should looks like subscribe({function1},{function2})

And never use Schedulers.newThread() for IO operations. Instead this prefer Schedulers.io(), because it use reusable threads from thread pool, while Schedulers.newThread() create just a new thread, which is not reusable

Comment: Ok, I changed the function in `Dao` to return Single<String>. Now, could you please show me how `function1` should looks like? How can I pass the String parameter, and how can i access the String inside `subscribe()` block

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The problem was the syntax: `()` was unnecessary, instead just `subscribe{ function1(jsonSTring) }` din the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you're looking for is this:

```
  DBManager.getEmployeesIdsJsonArray()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe( { jsonString ->
           // onNext
           // Do something with jsonString
        }, { throwable ->
           // onError
           // Do somethign with throwable
        } )
```

Comment: Thanks, but just writing `jsonString - >` wouldn't compile. For throwable, I already defined an `Action<Throwable>`

Comment: It doesn't know who is `jsonString`.